# FileInputStream(file) returning ENOENT (No such file or directory) android

Tags: java, android, file, base64

I'm trying to retrieve a file (any type) from file manager and encode this file in a Base64 String.
I've found a lot of answers involving IMAGES, but I need any type of file.
He's what I'm doing.

I'm retrieving a file(any type) from gallery like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose file"), GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in my result

```
Uri returnUri = intent.getData();
```

What gives me 'content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1646'

Then I try

```
File file = new File( returnUri.getPath() );
```

So far so good, but then I try to encode the file into a Base64 string:

```
    String str = null;
    try {
        str = convertFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the convertFile method

```
public String convertFile(File file)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);

    return encodedString;

}
```

And the loadFile method

```
private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        Log.i("MobileReport","Anexo -> loadfile(): File is too big!");
        // File is too large
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
           && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("It was not possible to read the entire file "+file.getName());
    }

    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

The error is in the first line of 'loadFile' method

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

The app crashes and in the log I got:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/1646: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I've declared the READ and WRITE permissions.
Could anyone help me with that error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`returnUri` is a `Uri`. It is not a filesystem path.

In particular, if you examine it, you will find that it is a `content://` `Uri`. To get an `InputStream` for that content, use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've tried 'getContentResolver().openInputStream(returnUri)' got File not found.

Comment: @HeitorColangelo: If you print `toString()` of `returnUri` to LogCat, what does it look like?

Comment: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1646

Comment: @HeitorColangelo: I have no idea why `openInputStream()` on that `Uri`, if you just got that `Uri` back from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, would result in a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I'll keep trying to solve.
As soon as I solve it I'll post here!

Comment: I get the same error, FileNotFoundException when using getContentResolver().openInputStream on content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/464

Comment: I had to deactivate this option from my app, but I'll try again on the next release. If i got the solution I'll post here.

Comment: This was years ago, but I've encountered the same issue. Any answer yet?

Comment: @Mr.Drew: The answer is the same now as it was then. Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. It handles both `file://` and `content://` schemes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/59123287/115145.

Comment: Wow, I was so young and innocent, poor 5 years younger Me.
The project was dropped so I never came back with an answer, but that is the correct one.