# i want to get actual file path of an existing file from device

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**i want to get actual file path of an existing file from device**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                String path = data.getData().getPath();
                txt_pathShow.setText(path);
            }}}}
```

Comment: Please read this article about **How to ask good questions** carefully and improve your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question does not provide enough information for anyone to properly help you.

Comment: Lay it down. You will not try to get a file path from a nice uri.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123162/android-kotlin-getting-a-filenotfoundexception-with-filename-chosen-from-file-p