# How to get file path from fileurl in qt android

Tags: android, qt, filedialog, file-uri

I am working on qt `5.14.1` with `ndk version 21` and `sdk version 28`. I want to open a `kml` file using file dialog in `qt android`. I get a fileurl from file dialog like this,

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Adocuments%2FAeroGCS%2FAeroGCSWorkspace%2FAbc5%2FBbb%2FBbb.kml`

but I didn't know how to convert this `URL` into a simple path and read the data from the file. Please tell me how can I convert this `URL` into a proper android path.

Comment: "I didnt know how to convert this url into simple path" -- you can't, in large part because it might not be a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59123162/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221312/115145 for more, though most of the material on this subject is based around traditional Java/Kotlin Android app development.

Comment: Pretty simple as all on  com.android.externalstorage points directly to a file. You see `AeroGCS%2FAeroGCSWorkspace%2FAbc5%2FBbb%2FBbb.kml` on primary. That is `AeroGCS/AeroGCSWorkspace/Abc5/Bbb/Bbb.kml` on external storage root. Hence `/storage/emulated/0/AeroGCS/AeroGCSWorkspace/Abc5/Bbb/Bbb.kml`

Comment: But... You do not need such a path as you can read the file using the obtained uri direcyly.

Comment: yes I know the path but how can I convert that url into proper file path to open a file.

Comment: or as you mentioned, how can I read file using url directly.