# How to convert File from URI in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-13

Convert URI into file and code should support android 7 to android 13.

```
`val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { uri ->
    // Callback is invoked after the user selects a media item or closes the
    // photo picker.
    if (uri != null) {
        
        Log.e("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: $uri")
    } else {
        Log.e("PhotoPicker", "No media selected")
    }
}`
```

I tried `uri.toFile()` but it's gives an error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://media/external/images/media/8596**

How to convert uri into file which can support all android version?

Comment: There is no requirement that the user picks something that you can access via the filesystem. Focus instead on using the `Uri` itself for whatever it is that you are trying to do. Most common uses, such as displaying the image or uploading it, do not require a `File`.

Comment: I need to save this uri to file because crop and compress will do on image so user can use that image wherever they want.

Comment: If you want to save a copy of the content, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Then, you can copy the bytes to some file that you control (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have example for that ? Any link about your last comment would be appreciate . Thanks

Comment: The linked-to duplicates demonstrate that, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62154537/115145).